# Python Search file for a string and get the string's line number

Tags: python

so im writing a login system with python and i would like to know if i can search a text document for the username you put in then have it output the line it was found on and search a password document. if it matches the password that you put in with the string on that line then it prints that you logged in. any and all help is appreciated.in my previous code i have it search line one and if it doesnt find the string it adds one to line then repeats till it finds it. then it checks the password file at the same line

```
def checkuser(user,line):  # scan the username file for the username
    ulines = u.readlines(line)
    if user != ulines:
        line = line + 1
        checkuser(user)
    elif ulines == user:
        password(user)
```

Comment: sorry kinda ignore that example its a portion cut out of the original code that is a lot longer. new tells if it is a new account or not. so if new =1 then it writes the username and password

Comment: @Cody Roberts you also want to search file first with username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fucntion to get the line number. You can use this how you want

```
def getLineNumber(fileName, searchString):
    with open(fileName) as f:
        for i,line in enumerate(f, start=1):
           if searchString in line: 
               return i
    raise Exception('string not found')
```

Comment: Small little suggestion: instead of `return i+1`, use `enumerate(f, start=1)` or `enumerate(f, 1)`, depending what you like better

Comment: what exactly is enumerate?

Comment: It gives you the index of the item currently being iterated over. Kind of like `for index, item in enumerate(my_list):`

Comment: @James Thanks for the suggestion :) !

Answer (score 4):

Pythonic way for your answer

```
f = open(filename)
line_no = [num for num,line in enumerate(f) if 'searchstring' in line][0]
print line_no+1
```

Comment: This answer appears to be faster than looping and is syntactically more compact.